# ECM and ARDL models in R

Tags: r

I have one data set and I want to calculate coefficients of elasticity with Error correction model-ECM and second is autoregressive distributed lag-ARDL. Data values are not in logarithms.
Equations for first model is ΔPt = a + b0ΔWt + b1Pt-1 + b2Wt-1 + et and equation with second model is Pt = a + b0P(t-1) + b1w(t) + b2w(t-1) + et.

```
    P              W
-------------------------------------------
2001    1,32225 10,75985
2002    1,4643  11,81686
2003    1,59008 12,75945
2004    1,72585 13,81505
2005    1,72579 14,61576
2006    1,93372 15,6497
2007    2,07582 17,21165
2008    2,41522 18,95588
2009    2,30599 18,78965
2010    2,27247 19,01828
2011    2,32    18,92123
2012    2,34942 18,48667
2013    2,18307 18,0731
2014    2,2474  18,38971
2015    2,33428 18,90066
2016    2,4385  19,74001
2017    NA      20,71245
----------------------------------------------
```

So at the end of this regressions results are:
-    ECM,   ΔPt= -2,67936+ 1,04514* ΔWt-1,27949 Wt-1
-    ARDL , Pt = -2,67936-0,27949P(t-1) + 1,045140248w(t) + 0,232898w(t-1)

So can anybody help me, how to solve these two examples with lm function or otherwise?